# Help reversing end-of-life'd Logitech Link. How to get Flash Contents

Tags: firmware, linux, embedded

See Update below.

I got an email from Logitech that they are End of Lifing their Harmony Link product (see https://community.logitech.com/s/question/0D55A0000745EkCSAU/harmony-link-eos-or-eol).

So I took it upon myself to start taking it apart. Peeling back the sticky pads on the bottom revealed 4 solder points. Two of which happen to UART connections.

Here is the info when booting:

```
++NAND: RCSR=54200900
Searching for BBT table in the flash ...
.
Found version 1 Bbt0 at block 1023 (0x7fe0000)
Total bad blocks: 0
.[Warning] FEC not connect right PHY: ID=fffffc
FEC: [ FULL_DUPLEX ] [ connected ] [ 100M bps ]:
Ethernet mxc_fec: MAC address sn:ip:ped:fr:om:vu
No IP info for device!
Unrecognized chip: 0xf8!!!
hardware reset by POR

Clock input is 24 MHz
RedBoot(tm) bootstrap and debug environment [ROMRAM]
Non-certified release, version FSL 200904 - built 21:32:37, Jul  5 2011

Platform: Logitech Baby (i.MX25 )  PASS 1.0 [x32 DDR]
System type 2070 revision 6
Copyright (C) 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004 Red Hat, Inc.
Copyright (C) 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006 eCosCentric Limited

RAM: 0x00000000-0x03f00000, [0x00095250-0x03ef1000] available
FLASH: 0x00000000 - 0x8000000, 1024 blocks of 0x00020000 bytes each.
== Executing boot script in 3.000 seconds - enter ^C to abort
RedBoot> ubi attach -f 0x80000 -l 0x07EC0000 -w 0x800 -e 0x20000 -s 0x200
scanning 1014 PEBs
........................................................................................................................................d
RedBoot> ubi load -b 0x100000 kernel%{os_backup}
RedBoot> exec -c %{os_cmdline}entry=0x80008000, target=0x80008000
Using base address 0x00100000 and length 0x0013a6d4
Uncompressing Linux..................................................................................... done, booting the kernel.
```

So it is running a booter called RedBoot. This seems to show the individual image files:

```
RedBoot> ubi info
Volumes count:                           8
Logical eraseblock size:                 129024
Total amount of logical eraseblocks:     1014 (130830336 bytes)
Amount of available logical eraseblocks: 337 (43481088 bytes)
Maximum count of volumes                 128
Count of bad physical eraseblocks:       0
Count of reserved physical eraseblocks:  10
Current min/mean/max erase counter:      2/5/9
Minimum input/output unit size:          2048 bytes
VID header offset:                       512
-----------------------------------
Volume ID:   0
Type:        static
Alignment:   1
Size:        17 LEBs (2228224 bytes)
Used:        10 LEBs (1287892 bytes)
State:       OK
Name:        kernel
-----------------------------------
Volume ID:   1
Type:        static
Alignment:   1
Size:        114 LEBs (14942208 bytes)
Used:        92 LEBs (11862016 bytes)
State:       OK
Name:        cramfs
-----------------------------------
Volume ID:   4
Type:        dynamic
Alignment:   1
Size:        25 LEBs (3276800 bytes)
State:       OK
Name:        mfgdata
-----------------------------------
Volume ID:   5
Type:        dynamic
Alignment:   1
Size:        261 LEBs (34209792 bytes)
State:       OK
Name:        storage
-----------------------------------
Volume ID:   6
Type:        static
Alignment:   1
Size:        25 LEBs (3276800 bytes)
Used:        10 LEBs (1287892 bytes)
State:       OK
Name:        kernel_sm
-----------------------------------
Volume ID:   7
Type:        static
Alignment:   1
Size:        114 LEBs (14942208 bytes)
Used:        102 LEBs (13033472 bytes)
State:       OK
Name:        cramfs_sm
-----------------------------------
Volume ID:   8
Type:        dynamic
Alignment:   1
Size:        25 LEBs (3276800 bytes)
State:       OK
Name:        usrconf
-----------------------------------
Volume ID:   9
Type:        dynamic
Alignment:   1
Size:        82 LEBs (10747904 bytes)
State:       OK
Name:        logitech
-----------------------------------
Volume ID:   2147479551
Type:        dynamic
Alignment:   0
Size:        0 LEBs (0 bytes)
State:       OK
Name:
```

Here's the question: Can anyone help me make use of this info? How can I best get the info off the device via this UART cable?  I've toyed with the `dump` command to various levels of success but that is pretty cumbersome just showing typical hex text in the form of 
`00139E70: F8 13 90 C7 98 3B 7B CF  04 9F 80 E1 9A FF 8B 68  |.....;{........h|` 
which is hard to do anything with. So, any ideas as to how I should proceed? Many thanks.

**Update:**
I've managed to dump (I think) the entire memory, but haven't gotten much out of it with Binwalk.
In case anyone else wants to take a look, here it is.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pxpugqpptqc3ph9/data-complete.bin

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to get hex output of the partition data, you can store it in a text file and then convert to a binary. On Linux, the following commands may help:

```
cat data.txt | cut -d' ' -f2-18 | sed s/\\s//g | tr -d '\n' | xxd -r -p > data.bin
```

Comment: That's much easier than what I was doing but is there an easy way you know of to output that? That's the part I'm having a harder time with.

Comment: What do you mean? You said you have access to dump command; start any terminal client, save the output (example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11420381/7303703), dump the whole partition to a text file, remove a few first lines and pass that file to a snippet I posted.

Comment: I guess I was more trying to figure out if there's a better command than just spewing it on the screen, which takes a considerable amount of time, and if I should just start at 0x000000 and pick some arbitrary number, or if based on what I already pasted there's a way to specifically target i.e. Volume ID 4.

Comment: Have you tried looking for dump command options, like offset and size? The whole storage size in this device can't be that big

Comment: It took 18 hours to dump, but I think I got it all.. https://www.dropbox.com/s/pxpugqpptqc3ph9/data-complete.bin binwalk doesn't get much useful info tho, sadly.

Comment: @justin from a quick look I wasn't able to understand partition scheme either, but there are a lot of strings and ARM (LE) function in there, I'd start with loading this whole file into a disassembler

Answer (score 1):

Have you been able to mount any portion of this dump as ubifs ?

```
$ strings data-complete.bin | grep -i ubi
"console=ttymxc1,115200 noinitrd init=/linuxrc ubi.mtd=1 root=/dev/mtdblock:cramfs%{os_backup} %{os_cmdargs}"
ubi attach -f 0x80000 -l 0x07EC0000 -w 0x800 -e 0x20000 -s 0x200
ubi load -b 0x100000 kernel%{os_backup}
"console=ttymxc1,115200 noinitrd init=/linuxrc ubi.mtd=1 root=/dev/mtdblock:cramfs%{os_backup} %{os_cmdargs}"
ubi attach -f 0x80000 -l 0x07EC0000 -w 0x800 -e 0x20000 -s 0x200
ubi load -b 0x100000 kernel%{os_backup}
*** invalid 'ubi' command: %s
ubi 
*** UBI is not attached
*** UBI is already attached
UBI start address
UBI length
Attach Unsorted Block Image [UBI]
[-f <ubi_addr> -l <ubi_length> -w <write_size> -e <erase_size> -s <subpage_size>]
Detach Unsorted Block Image [UBI]
Display contents of Unsorted Block Image [UBI]
Load image from Unsorted Block Image [UBI] into RAM
Erase an Unsorted Block Image [UBI]
Format using a UBI image
Manage UBI images
node with incompatible UBI version found: this UBI version is %d, image version is %d
this UBI version is %d, image version is %d
bad UBI magic %08lx, should be %08x
ubi attach -f 0x80000 -l 0x07EC0000 -w 0x800 -e 0x20000 -s 0x200
ubi load -b 0x100000 kernel%{os_backup}
"console=ttymxc1,115200 noinitrd init=/linuxrc ubi.mtd=1 root=/dev/mtdblock:cramfs%{os_backup} %{os_cmdargs}"
```

See for reference:

- [Weird binwalk output on GoPro Firmware](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6569/weird-binwalk-output-on-gopro-firmware)

Answer (score 0):

Until a better solution is found, Perhaps the 'EOL' process can be avoided by blocking this device from access to the outside internet (by blocking it at your router/gateway).

I have done this for an internet-enabled device that I don't trust to access the internet (it still works usefully on my LAN)